# Mocha Chai unit testing run specific folder

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have a application where it contains the test folder in main directory to maintain the `*test.js` files inside test folder. This test folder contains multiple sub folder representing each functionality and these sub folder conatains many `*test.js` files. How to run the specific testcase from selected folder in Mocha unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a structure similar to

```
testFolder
 |
 --> subtestFolder1
     |
     --> 1test.js
     --> 2test.js
 |
 --> subtestFolder2
     |
     --> ... 
 |
 --> subtestFolder3
     |
     --> ...
```

And you want to execute only tests existing into `subtestFolder1` folder, you have to execute mocha like this

`mocha testFolder/subtestFolder1/*test.js`